# Extract Unique Values from Three Lists on Three Worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook with multiple worksheets, but, three of them are inventory SKU lists at different locations. Each list at minimum is 8,000 SKUs that can repeat between the different locations. I'm hoping for a clever way to get around copying and pasting the three lists into a single column and then using remove duplicates. The hope would be to feed the three inventory lists into the spreadsheet month-to-month and have it automatically extract the unique values onto a fourth worksheet.

I'd like to shy away from VBA if possible. This workbook will leave my desk in the short future and I'd prefer not to support it past the initial buildout (person getting it is not well versed in macros). The preferred method would be a formula (non array), or maybe a Pivot table(s) method.

Any and all help is appreciated. The couple hours of research returns array formulas that are not an option for the workbook or the simple copy and paste method/remove duplicates method.

Thank you,

Sean

Comment: Use Power Query to pull the three tables into one continuous one and to remove duplicate rows.

Comment: @MarkS. Thank you for the suggestion! The only hang up with using Power Query is the worksheets I am combining are not tables. The time to make them tables and combine via Power Query is equal to the time to use the standard CTRL+C/CTRL+V > Remove Duplicates method. I didn't know about Power Query until now though, so I appreciate you bringing it up so I could learn about it.

Comment: To make them tables is sooooo easy. `CTRL` + `T` and it will become a reference-able table. From their you append the three tables to each other (as long as the headers are the same, shouldn't have issues). Remove whatever columns you don't need and remove duplicates. The originals will be maintained as they are, and the new table will provide your desired result. This method is scalable in that if more data gets added to any table, the query once refreshed will update accordingly without remapping the table range.

Comment: @MarkS. Alright you sold me. The initial problem with turning three worksheets into tables was the headers did not reside in the first column. In doing further research  into Power Queries, I decided to take it all as a learning experience and implement them. So a short macro later to remove the first two rows upon worksheet.update and I no longer have the table issue. Thank you for sticking with me on this one Mark and for clueing me into a new area of excel I wasn't familiar with.

Comment: I am so stoked for you to be learning some of the 'advanced' techniques. I put it in quotes, as I'm sure you've found they're very straightforward and easy to use, and makes work soo much easier, yet very few actually use this. Regarding the missing two rows, you can have a table anywhere on the sheet, you would simply refer to the name for the power query if the positioning is non-negotiable. I tend to keep sources tables top left (power queries, tables that feed them). Then when I make display 'tables' (not actual named ranges), I tend to give some space on the left and top to add filters.

Comment: This allows users to interact with the source table, but in a summarized way. For example, I'll have A1 labelled, Fiscal Year and then in B1 I'll have a data validation of the fiscal years available in the source table. Then the display table which is just sumifs or lookups will use that filter to summarize the data by whatever dimensions I setup (month, sales reps, product lines, whatever). Power Query becomes especially useful when connected to SQL databases. It allows you to define those pesky report criteria and eliminate all those extra columns and refresh easily.